# Torus bundle over sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $T\cong\mathbb C/\mathbb Z^2$ be a compact complex torus. 
What is an example of a nontrivial $G$-fiber bundle $$T\hookrightarrow E\to S^2\; ?$$

Comment: Is there supposed to be any compatibility of the action of $G$ on $E$ with the fiber bundle?

Comment: @hunter Yes indeed. Sorry!

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question, but in (complex) algebraic geometry, you can think of this as having a family of genus one curves varying over $\Bbb{P}^1$, since $\Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{C})\cong S^2$.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis but there is no nontrivial family of genus one curves varying over $\mathbb{P}^1$ (any projective flat family of elliptic curves has degenerate members)

Comment: I did not know this fact. I think I'll leave it here so people can see.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis I am wrong! Was presupposing the existence of a section. Without demanding a section you can get a non-trivial family over $\mathbb{P}^1$, which answers OP's question. Joel Fine's answer here does it: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12500/nontrivial-isotrivial-family-of-elliptic-curves

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is helpful for me.

Comment: $G=T$. Take $E=S^3\times S^1$, with the diagonal action. The projection map to $S^2$ is the map $E\xrightarrow{pr_1} S^3\xrightarrow{Hopf}S^2$.